# How to add elements from a list to another

Tags: python, list

I have two lists:

```
A = ['John,Male,20,','Jenny,Female,25','James,Male,30']
B = ['London','Paris','Washington']
```

Is there a way I can insert the values in the second list into the first list

Hypothetical output:

```
['John,Male,20,London','Jenny,Female,25,Paris','James,Male,30,Washington']
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `zip` to join the lists into lists of pairs. That would give you:

```
>>> zip(A, B)
[('John,Male,20,', 'London'), ('Jenny,Female,25', 'Paris'), 'James,Male,30', 'Washington')]
```

Then you can concatenate the strings in each pair using a list comprehension:

```
>>> [a + b for a, b in zip(A, B)]
['John,Male,20,London', 'Jenny,Female,25,Paris', 'James,Male,30,Washington']
```

Comment: perfect , although what would i do if i had to concatenate the ages instead and they were integers not strings ?